# parseDouble vs nextDouble

Tags: java, string, parsing, double

I have the folowing code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine()));
}
```

with input:

```
1.1
2.2
3.3
```

Program stops after reading this input whereas, as I assume, it should still read from input.
Why is that?

Comment: Because it doesn't know that you've finished entering numbers. Close the stream (e.g. press Ctrl-D)

Comment: No, it stops after reading this input, it should still read as I guess

Comment: But it doesn't know that nothing comes after it if you don't close the stream, so it just waits. [It works fine here](http://ideone.com/y19u7S).

Comment: *"Program stops after reading this input..."* It doesn't for me. If I keep going after typing in the above and type "4.4", I get back 4.4; then "5.5", I get back 5.5. If I then type "foo", it terminates.

Comment: I believe he's saying it doe stop executing, and does not await further input.

Comment: No, it should still read for the input but it stops

Comment: Michał Szewczyk's answer works for me, thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem could be that your **default locale** uses comma as delimiter.
**Double.parseDouble()** - uses always the dot as separator.
**in.nextDouble()** - uses separator specified by your Locale.
The result is that one of those methods can use comma as separator whereas the other use dot.

To solve that problem, you should unify the method of reading/parsing doubles from your input, and also decide which separator you want to use.
You can set the type of separator, for example by using:
  1. **Dot delimiter**:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

or:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useDelimiter("\\.");
```

2. **Comma delimiter**:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
```

or

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useDelimiter(",");
```

So refactoring your code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine()));
}
```

To see the problem clearly you can use this code:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRANCE);
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(in.hasNextDouble());
Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
```

with input: 1,1

Result of **hasNextDouble()** is true whereas **Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine())** throws NumberFormatException.

Hope it helps.